# Ubuntu/CentOS pipe к процессу по PID

Tags: linux, pipes

Доброго времени суток.
Требуется кидать данные процессу через пайп, по PID. Не понятно, как это сделать.
Ну то есть. Процесс запущен. Известен его PID.
надо изредка сделать что-то вроде:

```
cat something | PID:XXXX
```

Comment: вы не могли бы описать исходную задачу? зачем нужно что-то передавать процессу?

Comment: задача...хм...отладка в netbeans. там есть свои ограничения при отладке удаленной в разных системах...приходится извращаться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> что-то вроде:
>
> ```
> $ cat something | PID:XXXX
> ```

вероятно, имеется в виду запись в *stdin* процесса (если, конечно, процесс готов к этому):

```
$ cat something > /proc/XXXX/fd/0
```

Comment: возможно, что так. при случае попробую. спасибо. помечу как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Перед запуском процесса надо создать псевдотерминал pty/pts. Далее перенаправляешь stout/stdin/stderr в этот терминал pty. Когда необходимо пообщаться с програмкой - просто подключаешься к pts или делаешь эхо/кат туда.

Псевдотерминал работает как буфер, от которого можно отключиться не прервав выполнение программы.

В запущенном режиме только сама программа может переключить ввод вывод.

Для того чтоб не портить готовую програму скриптами можно сделать обертку в /usr/local/bin/

Если программа самописная, то лучше посмотреть в сторону сокетов для общения с пользователем и другими программами.